# Using Xerces C++ to generate XML from XSD using specific data

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces-c

Consider data from a database/other resource and a schema describing that data.

- How can you generate a XML document according to this schema and any facets/constraints it provides?
- Which API would best be suited for that task? Which hooks?

The startElement/endElement-approach of the SAX parser look promising, but those apply to parsing.

Comment: Search for "schema-directed editing". There may be many documents which are valid for a particular combination of schema and data, so to get useful results a human -- or a program -- must be in the loop to make decisions appropriat to the semantics. Schema just defines higher-order syntax.

Comment: I see this is quite an advanced topic. I shall leave this for a later time. Thank you anyway.

Comment: We did look at putting features into DOM Level 3 that would make implementing this easier,  but it was pretty clear that there was no consensus yet on what that API should look like so we shelved the idea.